# How can I make this light more realistic?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, photorealism

I need to know how to make this lighting more realistic. I'm using three objects for the light, the uppermost object having an emission node turned way up. This obviously does not look realistic.
[image: render with light]

Comment: Hard to give an advice without shareing that .blend bro... But if U only need that wall-light to look real than thats what the IES are for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UMMBqPU-bI

Comment: Not sure if this'll work, but what if you put more lights farther and farther away each time with fainter light, so it looked like it was giving off more light and dimming?

Comment: If the IES are problem for U please share the file with us using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I think tweaking the tone mapping will go a long way to giving a more photo realistic look. Give https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46825/599 a read (it's long, but worth it imo. The TL;DR is [enable filmic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46524/599))

Comment: Thanks guys this has been so helpful! I'm testing out an AI powered de-noiser and it really seems to be working well for me!
I will try tweaking tone mapping once I finish the doors and windows in this room.
I am trying to go for natural lighting as an experiment, and I love to use emission mappings as light sources.(even though they are messy as heck!)
I can't find filmic blender in my blender client for some reason, I thought it came with 2.8?
https://imgur.com/a/kvlVYaA
https://remingtongraphics.net/tools/d-noise/

Comment: New to this forum stuff, how do I like comments? lol